# How to implement Varnish within a Zend Framework 1.11 project

Tags: zend-framework, varnish, esi

I don't know much about Varnish, but as far as I know, I need to include ESI tags inside my views, is it right ?

Does any of you have any feedbacks on implementing such architecture?

I already found some view helpers to set ESI tags but I'm not sure that they're really efficient.

I'd like to use Varnish to cache my homepage for let's say from 10 to 30 seconds.

Is it easy to do that with ZF?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use ESI ?

ESI was useful before AJAX rised.

Today, developers prefer AJAX because ESI makes you dependant of  your cache engine (your site won't work without cache).

You don't need ESI to use Varnish; you need Varnish (or any ESI compliant cache system) to use ESI.

ESI or AJAX will be necessary only if you need to mix different cache TTL into a single page.

If you want to cache your whole home page as a single object, just run Varnish in front of your web server and don't change anything to your PHP code, it's just Varnish setup with some VCL to cache your home page only.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I though I needed to use ESI to activate Varnish but I got it, thanks.

Comment: A last but not least, how does it work with session ? If the users don't hit the php server but varnish, how my session will work ?

Comment: You should create another question on this subject but basically, sessions are often managed with cookies, and therefore should not be cached. Ask yourself a question : what is the use of sessions ? Should a request based on session data (=personalized) be cached ?

Comment: I know about that, but my site is a collaborative website, therefore cookies/sessions are used everywhere, does it mean I can't use Varnish?

Comment: By nature, massively dynamic websites aren't easy to cache. You will have to play with Ajax or ESI to separate generic (cachable) and specific (not cachable) contents into separate requests. But you can't really cache content that changes all the time. That said, once you're able to tell Varnish which content you can cache, you can also ask varnish to delete cookies for these requests. You're then able to safely cache dynamic (not specific) content with no session sharing (which is the biggest risk with HTTP caching).

Comment: Note that if you receive massive load on specific pages, maybe you can tolerate to slightly reduce freshness of your content by caching it with a short TTL. Example : it is useful to cache a page for 1 minute if you know it will be asked many times a minute. But you still can't/shouldn't use sessions. Sessions should only be used to generate user specific content, wich is rarely cached/cachable. If you want to cache user specific content, you will have to add your session ID into Varnish object hash (req.hash += ...) because every user needs a different content for the same URL.